# What is the working load limit of a 18-foot 4x6 pine beam?

Tags: porch-swing

Can you give me the load limit on a 4x6 pine board 18' long used for a swing set?  Thank you

Comment: Hi, Joan, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Are you asking about the weight of the board, or the load capacity of the board?

Comment: Also, will the beam span 18 feet, or is it like a typical swingset where part of it cantilevers?

Comment: Is it supported at the ends (18 foot span) or somewhere else? i.e. legs 12 feet apart with 3 feet sticking out at the ends, or 3 sets of legs 9 feet apart, or two sets of legs 18 feet apart? Beam calculators are not too hard to find, but for a swing set you might want to increase the safety factor (amount by which you exceed the expected load when calculating.) Grade of the lumber also matters.

Comment: ...I'm betting there's a 90+ percent chance OP is asking how much weight can hang from the 4"x6"x18' pine beam. +1 so she can upload a helpful drawing or picture or something.

Comment: The beam is 18' long supported on each end, no support in middle.  Not sure of the grade of lumber.  I just need to know worst case how much weight can the swings support.  Sorry I don't have a picture or more info.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it’s “Lodgepole Pine” (Idaho Pine and Ponderosa Pine is slightly less) and it’s grade is a No. 2 and better (no loose or missing knotholes), then a 4x6 spanning 18’ will support about 105 lbs. loaded at the mid-span (slightly higher if it’s loaded at third points or further from the center point).

Comment: Is there any resource that lists maximal admissible workload of various beam/planks? In case I want to check a similar-yet different configuration.

Comment: @ebo I’ve seen structural tables on the internet. Maybe Google “Structural beam tables”.

Comment: as a non-native speaker, thanks for the keyword!

Answer (score 0):

Better idea instead of the 4x6 use 2 2x8 boards bolted of nailed together. Ive done this on a 18 foot span and it holds 3 large adults (over 200 lbs each) on swings without any flex or bowing. Outdoors i would use a good grade of treated lumber to prevent decay from the elements and longer life.